# Microsoft Defender treating Java class as a virus and blocking the service

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, antivirus

In our project code, one of the classes is being treated as a Trojan by Microsoft ATP Defender. Due to this, Microsoft defender is blocking the service on my laptop and not letting it run throwing the below error -

Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task ':api:compileJava' property 'destinationDir' during up-to-date check.

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'FareInfo.class' as it does not exist.

This is happening on all the machines with Microsoft Defender installed. We do not have the option of removing or turning off the Microsoft Defender.
Below is the code for this class, can someone please suggest what we can do to resolve this issue?

public class FareInfo {

```
public final String fareClass;
public final String fareBasisCode;
public final ImmutableMap<SMSTaxCategory, Double> taxes;
public final double baseFare;
public final ImmutableMap<SMSFeeCategory, Double> fees;
public final int fareID;

public FareInfo(String fareClass, String fareBasisCode, Double baseFare, ImmutableMap<SMSTaxCategory, Double> taxes, int fareID) {
    this.fareClass = fareClass;
    this.fareBasisCode = fareBasisCode;
    this.baseFare = baseFare;
    this.taxes = taxes;
    this.fees = ImmutableMap.of();
    this.fareID = fareID;
}

@JsonCreator
public FareInfo(@JsonProperty("fareClass") String fareClass,
                @JsonProperty("fareBasisCode") String fareBasisCode,
                @JsonProperty("baseFare") Double baseFare,
                @JsonProperty("taxes") ImmutableMap<SMSTaxCategory, Double> taxes,
                @JsonProperty("fees") ImmutableMap<SMSFeeCategory, Double> fees,
                @JsonProperty("fareID") int fareID) {
    this.fareClass = fareClass;
    this.fareBasisCode = fareBasisCode;
    this.baseFare = baseFare;
    this.taxes = taxes;
    this.fees = fees;
    this.fareID = fareID;
}

public static FareInfo copy(FareInfo fareInfo, Map<SMSTaxCategory, Double> taxes) {
    return new FareInfo(fareInfo.fareClass, fareInfo.fareBasisCode, fareInfo.baseFare, ImmutableMap.copyOf(taxes), fareInfo.fees, fareInfo.fareID);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    FareInfo fareInfo = (FareInfo) o;
    return fareID == fareInfo.fareID &&
            Objects.equals(fareClass, fareInfo.fareClass) &&
            Objects.equals(fareBasisCode, fareInfo.fareBasisCode) &&
            Objects.equals(baseFare, fareInfo.baseFare) &&
            Objects.equals(taxes, fareInfo.taxes) &&
            Objects.equals(fees, fareInfo.fees);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(fareClass, fareBasisCode, baseFare, taxes, fees, fareID);
}
```

Comment: Turn off microsoft defender ?

Comment: There is no option to turn off or remove microsoft defender

Comment: @Divya This is not the exact answer to your question, but I simply wanted to point out that you can always disable Microsoft Defender in Windows 10's settings. Just Google it and you'll find out exactly how to do it.

Comment: Is creating an MD5 hash for a class file part of your application logic or are you trying to build your application (again in every target environment)?

Comment: @Holger it is a part of Application logic

Comment: I believe we can add exception to defender I mean `firewall` where in you can allow JRE/JDK so that applications executing through it won't be blocked. I think any which ways for the first time, windows must give a firewall pop up , where you allow access or deny !